# Checking if a username is already in the database c#

Tags: c#, database

I am currently trying to do so that when you create a new user on my website, it should check in the database table `brugere` if the name already exists, and if it does, it shouldn't create a new user.

But I can't get it to work....

```
bool exists = false;

// create a command to check if the username exists
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand())

cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from brugere where bruger_navn = @bruger_navn";
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("bruger_navn", txtUsername.Text);
    exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
}

// if exists, show a message error
if (exists)
    Label1. Text = "This username has been using by another user."; 
else
{
    // does not exists, so, persist the user
    using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand())
        cmd2.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO brugere (bruger_navn, Bruger_pass) VALUES (@bruger_navn, @bruger_pass)";
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("bruger_navn", txtUsername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("bruger_pass", txtPassword.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

conn.Close();
```

Comment: You missed `@` in front of your `bruger_navn` parameter. It should be `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bruger_navn", txtUsername.Text);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you are missing `@` before param names

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bruger_navn", txtUsername.Text);
....
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bruger_navn", txtUsername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bruger_pass", txtPassword.Text);
```

Also, you need to specify a `Connection` property for a `SqlCommand`

```
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand())
{
   cmd1.Connection = conn;
```

Or

```
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = conn.CreateCommand())
{
```

Also, you have some chaos with braces and variables names, as I consider code should be similar to

```
bool exists = false;

// create a command to check if the username exists
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd1.CommandText = "select count(*) from brugere where bruger_navn = @bruger_navn";
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("bruger_navn", txtUsername.Text);
    exists = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
}

// if exists, show a message error
if (exists)
   Label1. Text = "This username has been using by another user."; 
else
{
    // does not exists, so, persist the user
    using (SqlCommand cmd2 = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd2.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO brugere (bruger_navn, Bruger_pass) VALUES (@bruger_navn, @bruger_pass)";
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("bruger_navn", txtUsername.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("bruger_pass", txtPassword.Text);

        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

conn.Close();
```

Comment: Oh gosh :D Thanks. But I added the @'s to the param names and it still comes up with the error msg that the username is already taken when I try to create a new user that does not exist? No habla SQL senior :O

Comment: @Nicolaj I've updated the answer, also added the full code, try it.

Comment: what does the schema of the table look like?, is the username a key field also ` cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` wrap that around a `try{}catch(SqlDbException sqlDbEx){ }` so that you can trap proper exeptions